# App crash using iCloud Key-Value storage writing

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

My app crashes every time I try to set a value for a key using iCloud key-value storage...

I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:     '[<NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore 0x13fd5b8a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class     is not key value coding-compliant for the key ladies.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1842f0f48 0x19979bf80 0x1842f0c08 0x18516c014 0x1000e5380 0x1000e9914     0x1000f0430 0x1000f046c 0x1000f04a0 0x1000f04e4 0x1898bf240 0x1898bed3c     0x1898bebc4 0x189085c2c 0x101429c68 0x10142f710 0x1842a81f8 0x1842a6060 0x1841d4ca0 0x18f758088 0x1898ecffc 0x1000f4564 0x199fde8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I define my keystore:

```
var iCloudStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
```

Set my value like this:

```
iCloudStore.setValue(experience, forKey: "experience")
```

Why is this not working? Do I have to define that key for it to work? I really don't understand the error i get...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`setValue:forKey:` is not a method on `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()` used to save data to an iCloud key-value store. Instead, it is the method from the `NSKeyValueCoding` protocol that is used for more general key-value coding with the types `NSValue` and `NSNumber`. The error you received refers to you attempting to access the “experience” key on your `iCloudStore` object itself rather than in the iCloud key-value store.

The methods available on `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()` to save key-value pairs are:

- `setArray:forKey:`
- `setBool:forKey:`
- `setData:forKey:`
- `setDictionary:forKey:`
- `setDouble:forKey:`
- `setLongLong:forKey:`
- `setObject:forKey:`
- `setString:forKey:`

Choose the method that best fits your type.

Comment: So the iCloud equivalent of NSUserdefauls.setValue is setObject?

Comment: Choose the method that best fits your type. `setObject:forKey:` is probably the most generic of all of the methods and will probably work but it's better to be specific if possible.

Comment: In some cases, like with `NSUserDefaults`, when you call `setValue:forKey:` you are getting the equivalent behavior to `setObject:forKey:`. To answer your original question, yes, `setObject:forKey:`, for iCloud, represents what `setValue:forKey:` does for you on `NSUserDefaults`.